# Jpgraph shows broken icons

Tags: php, graph, jpgraph

I am using jpgraph in laravell 4 on ubutu, every thing is look like correct but out put is below, where is problem please help

> require(Config::get('paths.storage') . "jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php");
>
> require(Config::get('paths.storage') . "jpgraph/src/jpgraph_bar.php");

```
                    $data1y = array(47, 80, 40, 116);
                    $data2y = array(61, 30, 82, 105);
                    $data3y = array(115, 50, 70, 93);



                    $graph = new Graph(350, 200, 'auto');
                    $graph->SetScale("textlin");

                    $theme_class = new UniversalTheme;
                    $graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

                    $graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150), array(15, 45, 75, 105, 135));
                    $graph->SetBox(false);

                    $graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
                    $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
                    $graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
                    $graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false, false);


                    $b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
                    $b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
                    $b3plot = new BarPlot($data3y);


                    $gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot, $b2plot, $b3plot));

                    $graph->Add($gbplot);


                    $b1plot->SetColor("white");
                    $b1plot->SetFillColor("#cc1111");

                    $b2plot->SetColor("white");
                    $b2plot->SetFillColor("#11cccc");

                    $b3plot->SetColor("white");
                    $b3plot->SetFillColor("#1111cc");

                    $graph->title->Set("Bar Plots");


                    $graph->Stroke()
```

> OUPUT

�PNG  IHDR^�/� pHYs���+ �IDATx���LU�����^@ҁ8�s�+4�+r+f��$k�JM�Ж��bA��twT+'�.$K�cZ��-�t:���K���?κ_���r����}>�p��{8�}*�s~�����$��iZ� �D��р��F�K�6�wk]���2���9s��ŋsrr"##'��Y�f-]�t�ƍaaa����,����N�|�,˲,777�߿?**j�Ν�������tVUU�R$|��g0���֬Y�L���|���?�8::�dɒ-[�(��F�q�ƍ�������km���yyy6l�����������ɓ�$-*����^���W�ʟ�ء���j�vvv*����M�Fc�1j�y�����C���>e���8==�СC���555�%�駪�� rab���������?��smm��O(#e�����k�~���w�>���� �a��Ɵ; ݽ{���j�*/^|���������a��

Comment: it's an encoding issue

Comment: what is solution ?

Comment: you're going to need to post your code

Comment: now you can see my code